# "unknown type name" when binding TPM Based Services' tbs.h using bindgen

Tags: c, rust, bindgen

I'm trying to bind `tbs.h` (TPM Based Services) via rust-bindgen.

I have the following header:

```c
#ifndef TPM_WRAPPER_H
#define TPM_WRAPPER_H
#include <tbs.h>
#endif
```

The `build.rs` file contains the path to the include directory of the Windows SDK:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=tbs");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/tpm_wrapper.h");

    let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default()
        .header("include/tpm_wrapper.h")
        .clang_arg("-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.19041.0/shared")
        .clang_arg("-v")
        .parse_callbacks(Box::new(bindgen::CargoCallbacks))
        .generate()
        .expect("Unable to generate bindings");

    let out_path = PathBuf::from(env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap());
    bindings
        .write_to_file(out_path.join("tpm_bindings.rs"))
        .expect("Couldn't write bindings!");
}
```

When I try to create the bindings via `cargo build` and run the build script, I get the following errors:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.19041.0/shared\tbs.h:50:9: error: unknown type name 'UINT8'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.19041.0/shared\tbs.h:99:5: error: unknown type name '_In_'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.19041.0/shared\tbs.h:99:31: error: expected ')'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.19041.0/shared\tbs.h:98:20: note: to match this '('
```

Is there some clang configuration missing?

Comment: Unfortunately, the [winapi](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/issues/787) crate is still missing the binding.

Comment: Try to `#include <windef.h>` ahead of `<tbs.h>`. That should take care of the primitive type-defs, though I'm not sure it will also include the respective header(s) for the SAL annotations (`_In_`, etc.).

Comment: I tried it, but received new errors. According to [rust ffi](https://anssi-fr.github.io/rust-guide/07_ffi.html) the SAL annotated code shall be handled accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting errors are part of the [windows-gnu toolchain](https://github.com/godot-rust/godot-rust/blob/master/gdnative-sys/build.rs#L197). Switching to `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` did the trick.

```
rustup toolchain add stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

The `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` requires the windows build tools available from the visual studio installer, or even as standalone.

*update*

`tbs.h` obviously needs `windows.h` for all windows defined types.
Due to a [bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-bindgen/issues/1556) in bindgen, there is a workaround blacklisting certain [functions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-bindgen/issues/1556#issuecomment-658317813)